# PHP - Readfile being slow, what are my options

Tags: php, asp-classic

I'm trying out at PHP for the first time (coming from classic ASP) and I'm testing loading a remote image and displaying it, using READFILE. During testing, I noticed a huge difference in return times compared to my old ASP script, which does exactly the same thing, pretty much. The PHP version actually took twice as long to load.

Here is my PHP, which is only 3 little lines of code:

```
<?php
$url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/file.jpg";
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); 
readfile($url);
?>
```

Here is my ASP version:

```
<%
Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHTTP.Open "GET", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/file.JPG"
objHTTP.Send
Set Jpeg = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Jpeg")
Jpeg.OpenBinary(objHTTP.responseBody)
Jpeg.SendBinary
%>
```

Why is my old, finished, dead, deprecated, old-school, diseased Classic ASP version doing much better than good old PHP? The ASP version is actually doing more than the PHP version. Is there something else I can use apart from READFILE that could be quicker? Am I using READFILE correctly? I'm not saying I'm looking at my clock waiting, both load in a split second, but PHP has a very noticeable delay.

Comment: Hm, funny, I really wonder, that the PHP version is much slower. Did you measured both on equivalent infrastructure? E.g. both locally?

Comment: Yes, tested both locally. It is bazaar.

Comment: You should ensure that output buffering is disabled.

Comment: what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @BurningtheCodeigniter: Really? I have to upgrade PHP 5.2.17 to get faster READFILE results, when I'm comparing it to Classic ASP that was last updated 12 years ago - doesn't make sense, but could be I suppose.

Comment: I would upgrade it but I'm using AWS S3 storage quite heavily in my application and in their documentation, it suggests that 5.2.17 is one of the highly-preferred versions.

Comment: @NikiC: Interesting about Output Buffering. Before I look at the configuration file to check output buffering, can I use **ob_flush()** just after **readfile**?

Comment: @NikiC: Just checked and Output Buffering is "off".

Comment: I have removed my answer due to the second downvoter that didn't leave a comment. I hope you had the time to test it. Stackoverflow should require an explanation for downvoting!

Comment: @WouterH: That's a real shame, it shouldn't be allowed! I asked for alternatives and you gave one, a worthy one at that. Unfortunately, I didn't have time to grab it and test it, although I would still like to. I came on here to get it and it was gone.

Comment: I suppose you are doing this just for testing purposes, right? Because having a file on a S3 bucket just to retrieve it on your server and send it using your bandwidth defies all the purpose of a CDN. You should display the file URL directly to the browser and let Amazon handle the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: You state PHP 5.2

Please note that 5.2 is no longer supported; you really should upgrade (and if it's a third party ISP providing it, then you should upgrade from them; no ISP should be providing an unsupported version of PHP -- it's a glaring security risk).

The other reason to upgrade is that PHP 5.3 is significantly faster than 5.2. And 5.4 is significantly faster than 5.3. If you're worried about speed, then you really must use the latest version.

Other thoughts?

Your PHP and ASP code probably aren't on the same server, right? Are there any differences between the two servers? Processor speed, memory, network speed? And are there any limits on the resources given to your program out of those items?

Given that what you're doing is fetching a file from a remote URL, I would suggest that server or network performance is more likely to be an issue here than program performance.

Comment: My PHP and ASP are on the same Windows 2008 server. Interesting comment about versions though, thanks.

Comment: A script that simple wouldn't be affected by PHP version differences - the majority of execution time is going to be sucked up by the HTTP overhead being performed in the background by readfile, plus all the metaoverhead, such as DNS looks.